# Implement chain of responsibility in StructureMap

Tags: design-patterns, structuremap, chain-of-responsibility

Imagine I implement the chain of responsibility design pattern in the following classes;

```cs
interface IDoStuff
{
  IDoStuff Next {get;}

  void Configure();
}

class StepOne
{
  public IDoStuff Next {get; set}

  public StepOne(IDoStuff next)
  {
    Next = next;
  }

  public void Configure()
  {
    // Do configuration relevant to StepOne

    // Call the next configure step in the chain
    Next?.Configure()
  }
}

class StepTwo
{
  public IDoStuff Next {get; set}

  public StepTwo(IDoStuff next)
  {
    Next = next;
  }

  public void Configure()
  {
    // Do configuration relevant to StepTwo

    // Call the next configure step in the chain
    Next?.Configure()
  }
}
```

I tried to configure the chain like this

```cs
class MyRegistry : Registry
{
  public MyRegistry()
  {
    For<IDoStuff>().Use<StepOne>();
    For<StepOne>().Use(c => new StepOne(c.GetInstance<StepTwo>()));
    For<StepTwo>().Use(c => new StepTwo(null));
  }
}
```

But instead I get this error from StructureMap;

> Bi-directional dependency relationship detected!
>   Check the StructureMap stacktrace below:
>   1.) IDoStuff (StepOne)
>   2.) new StepOne(*Default of IDoStuff*)
>   3.) StepOne
>   4.) Instance of IDoStuff (StepOne)
>   5.) Container.GetInstance()

What is the correct way of registering the chain?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I do not need the first line in the registry. It should be like this;

```cs
class MyRegistry : Registry
{
  public MyRegistry()
  {
    For<IDoStuff>().Use(c => new StepOne(c.GetInstance<StepTwo>()));
    For<StepTwo>().Use(c => new StepTwo(null));
  }
}
```

Then the chain will be constructed so that if you do `container.GetInstance<IDoStuff>()` it will give you a chain that goes `StepOne` => `StepTwo` => `null`.